# Does Google Drive Activity API expose view as an action?

Tags: google-drive-api

I've managed to get the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/activity/v2/requests#filtering) to run against a Google doc in my personal drive (of a Corporate paid account) using their example (after correcting for Python 2 syntax).

However, it shows only `edit` and `comment` as primary actions in that history, I don't see any actions saying just `view`.

Does that mean that there is no action recorded for document views? or that they are simply recorded as `comment` or something else, since the document URL always seems to redirect to `.../edit` even if I only grant View privileges.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `view` [action detail](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list) in Drive Activity API.

`edit` or `comment` action detail cannot be used to get `view` action history.

I tried to view a document and get all its activity and there is no new record seen (either `view`, `edit` or `comment`).

---

If you want to get the view history of a document, here are some of your options:

1. Use Drive API [Files:get()](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started), it will return a [file resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive) which contains `viewedByMe` flag and `viewedByMeTime` datetime parameter.

> It will only show the last time you viewed the file. If the file is shared, you cannot use this to get the recent datetime the file was viewed by other user.

2. If you have an admin account, you can use [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list) in [Admin SDK Reports API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/get-start/getting-started) to access Drive audit logs which contains view log activities and other events. See [Drive Audit Activity Events](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/activity/drive) for a list of events available.

**Sample [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list) Request Parameters:**

```
userKey: all
applicationName: drive
eventName: view
filters: doc_id==13NgKy87BggedOXnmkymygTyEh0xxxxxxxx
```

> **NOTE:**
>
> - If the file was viewed by a user outside your organization, the email address will not be available (User is anonymous)
> - Drive audit logs has a data retention time of 6 months. You can access Drive audit logs data this far back.
>
> **References:**
>
> - [View user Google Drive file activity](https://support.google.com/a/answer/4579696?hl=en)
> - [Data retention and lag times](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7061566?hl=en)

Comment: You might also want to file a feature request in [https://issuetracker.google.com/](https://issuetracker.google.com/) if you think this would be necessary